# Diiffernce Between Did and Have

Tags: questions, do, have

I am new here and I am beginner in English. Can anyone explain me the difference between these 2 sentences and also which one is wrong.

> "Did you see my DP?"

or

> "Have you seen my DP?"

Please explain me the Answer and which one is right and why?

Comment: Neither one is wrong. Both are in use.The first is past tense , and the second is a perfect construction and possibly more formal..

Comment: Could you explain which sentence we use for writing and which one for speaking

Comment: Well, you wouldn't exactly use this type of question in writing, unless maybe in texting...and that is usually informal. So if you are really asking when to use past and perfect, you will need a better example. ..but your post is possibly too broad, and without doubt has been asked here before many times.

Comment: @Cascabel could you help me ? Please

Comment: see: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118275/simple-past-and-present-perfect/118279#118279

Answer (score 0):

Both "Did you see my DP?" and "Have you seen my DP?" are correct for written as well as oral conversations.

But if you want to know the difference between Did and Have, then here it is:

**Did** you see is used only for the **Past Indefinite/Simple Tense**. (Like we used 'see' which is in simple tense with 'did'). It works for works for recent past till now.

**Have** you seen is used in the **Present Perfect Tense**. (Like we used 'seen' which is in present perfect tense with 'have'). It works for anything that still applies from any time till the present, thus emphasises on the present.

*For example:*

> Did you see the new movie? (A movie once released can be seen any
>   time. So it can be past or present both.)
>
> Have you seen the new episode? (A TV episode airs only on a particular
>   day, so it's something very close to present.)

**But for DP it can be seen at any time and also recently (because people change their DP frequently)**

> Present Perfect only emphasises on the present. It doesn't change the
>   meaning. So, both are correct but have a very minute difference.

**[Here's a great video to clarify this confusion.](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjtzaPtgIXjAhWVbysKHS1RBh0QtwIwAXoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D61vXRGJgUH0&usg=AOvVaw337uGIv-GNmlyiXmFYMwmh)**